# What is $\alpha^{\vee}$ for any root $\alpha$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\alpha_i, i \in I$ be simple roots in a root system and $\omega_i, i \in I$ the fundamental weights. The fundamental roots are dual to the fundamental coweights and the fundamental weights are dual to the fundamental coroots: $\alpha_i(\omega_j^{\vee}) = \delta_{ij}$, $\omega_i(\alpha_j^{\vee})=\delta_{ij}$. What is $\alpha^{\vee}$ for any root $\alpha$ in the root system? For example, in type $A_2$, what is $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)^{\vee}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually $\alpha^\vee$ denotes $2\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$, where $(\bullet, \bullet)$ denotes the inner product of your root system. The set of coroots also generates a root system.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas, thank you very much. I would like to think $\alpha^{\vee}$ as an element in the space generated by $\alpha_i^{\vee}$ and express $\alpha^{\vee}$ as a linear combination of $\alpha_i^{\vee}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724491/how-to-prove-that-b-vee-is-a-base-for-coroots